# Efficient way of retreiving index of dictionary entry by key in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

As I understand it, dictionaries in Python are ordered as of Python 3.7. Given a dictionary with N entries, I should be able to associate to each key an index from 0 to N-1. My question is, given a key, is there any way to retrieve this index in an efficient manner? It seems like there should be a more efficient way than retrieving the list of keys and searching for the specific key of interest.

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Dicts are accessed by keys, not indices. The change in 3.7 was that normal dicts were guaranteed to maintain insertion order, but to my knowledge there were no new tools added to *determine* that order. You may want to consider using an `OrderedDict` instead.

Comment: @MattDMo the use case is that I have is that I have a collection of items that can most conveniently be accessed via a key associated with them. However, I also want to build vectors/matrices associated with these items, where each basis element corresponds to each of these items. As such, having a 0 to N-1 index corresponding to each of these items seems natural. I'm not sure how much advice you can give with this limited description of my problem, but if there is another data structure that sounds better suited for this, I would appreciate pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you change the dict much, in particular delete items from it?

Comment: @KellyBundy Nope, the dictionary is static once it's been built.

Comment: Then build a second dict, mapping the keys to indexes.

Comment: Ah, that would work, thanks. I thought the index might be easily accessible with the original dictionary, but that's beginning to sound unlikely.

Comment: No the index is not easily accessible, because there's no need for it to be.

Comment: If you delete an item from the middle, half of the indexes would change, so I'd be surprised if indexing were supported.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to do this is `list(dict_name.keys()).index(key_name)`. Another way would be using `operator.indexOf`. I'm not sure why you would need the index of the keys in the first place, as getting a value from a dictionary is already O(1), or constant time.

Comment: That's not the only way (and `operator.indexOf` might be more efficient).

Comment: I timed it, and ```operator.indexOf``` and ```list(dict_name.keys()).index(key_name)``` were about the same speed. You are right that it would not be the only way though.

Comment: Can you include/share your timing code?

Comment: I just made a dictionary ```d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6, "z": 26}``` and timed each function finding the index of the letter "z" using time in the terminal. Both took about 0.026s on average. It would probably work better using a longer dictionary, but I don't really know. You can try using a longer dictionary to see if there's a difference.

Comment: There's no way that took 0.026s. It's about 100000 times faster than that. Tried that myself now, times were [424 ns for yours and 232 ns for indexOf](https://tio.run/##NY/bTsMwDIbv/RRWb5KgaFAKE0zaM/AAiIuOuCIqOSjxpA3Esxc3BUvRJzv/70O@8keKw1MuyzKVFJB9IM/oQ06FsVCmkQEq8TnjEZVS0GQpUxk5lX@hj44uLxOAE9V3N3YH7C12J@G98F04CJ3wQUjCR@Ek3Au/Vt3@B2ZxSwLrHKBLLlUKr4AS6tNX1m4307VqY3Ztop6Nstv33wbaWWzFN4Ao5v5uDZhkVZItcWt6g8Oh2VgkwUe9HarJYjvVYjyHE5VjNAZvMTZtLj6yXh9Lg56ejUUVKyqLZJblFw).